# Postfixadmin sending of e-mail fails with an error

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I recently installed a mail server on a Debian with postfix/dovecot with postfixadmin to manage virtual users but when sending a mail to users it doesn't reach the destination and the logs return me this error :

> net_connect_unix(/var/run/dovecot/stats-writer) failed: Permission
> denied))

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Dovecot now includes a statistics module and gives an error if it is not defined in the configuration.

In order to make it simple just create a new file and edit it like this

`vi /etc/dovecot/conf.d/30-service-stats.conf`

```
service stats {
   
    unix_listener stats-reader {
        user = vmail
        group = vmail
        mode = 0660
    }

    unix_listener stats-writer {
        user = vmail
        group = vmail
        mode = 0660
    }
}
```

Restarting dovecot should get rid of your error.